# Довольно отравляющий - корректно ли ставить рядом эти два слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Контекст такой:
-Не пойму, в чём дело, но у меня дома стоит невыносимый запах.
-Что за запах?
*-Довольно отравляющий.* Мне было как-то не по себе последние несколько дней.
Допустимо ли использовать такое словосочетание? И если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В словарях одно из значений слова "довольно" - достаточно, в значительной мере (это ваш случай), с указанием на употребление - с наречиями и прилагательными. В вашем примере "отравляющий" - это причастие. Поэтому, как мне кажется, не стоит употреблять его со словом "довольно". Да и слух режет. Думаю, что это связано со степенью сравнения. Не может быть сочетаний "очень отравляющий" и др., а с прилагательными такие сочетания возможны. 
Если требуется оставить слово "довольно", то  проще добавить прилагательное, например: "довольно сильный (едкий, тяжелый и т.п.), отравляющий".

Comment: Вот мне тоже как-то режет слух, ощущение что это из разряда "немножко беременна"... Думала, может, это из-за причастия, но в принципе такие сочетания вполне жизнеспособны, "довольно впечатляющий" например. 
Но вы правы, если подставить "очень", то всё встает на свои места, это хороший способ проверки.

Answer (score 4):

Похоже на контаминацию *ядовитый-отравляющий*. Если "довольно ядовитый" вполне себе используется, то "довольно отравляющий" звучит не совсем по-русски.

Comment: Спасибо, вы подтвердили мои догадки по поводу не совсем русского звучания и пополнили мой лексикон словом контаминация:)

Answer (score 1):

Отравляющий - тот, который отравляет. И не важно, в какой степени. В данном случае слово "довольно" можно и не использовать. Но мысли автора неисповедимы:)

Comment: Дело в том, что это не совсем авторская мысль, это перевод, тут уже другие требования.

Answer (score 1):

У вас задача обосновать/опровергнуть правильность или найти лучший вариант?

Строго говоря, никаких причин для запрещения такого сочетания я не вижу. Да, отравляющий - причастие. Но это никаких ограничений не накладывает. К тому же тут  используется как прилагательное. Тут скорее для относительных прилагательных (типа деревянный или врачебный) можно какие-то ограничения накладывать. А коли причастия позволяет образовать сравнительные степени ("более отравляющий") и подобные (сильно отравляющий, смертельно отравляющий и проч.), почему в этом ряду не может быть и ***довольно отравляющий***?

Что же касается конкретного примера, то тут, согласен, несколько режет слух. В данном случае уровень этой "отравляющей" способности как-то не очень понятна. То ли это действительно некая характеристика отраления, то ли степень уверенности говорящего, в том, что газ отравляющий. В зависимости от смысла и надо править.

Если первое, то поскольку говорящий жив и видимо, здоров, то скорее всего речь идет о том, насколько этот запах *неприятен*. А потому газ ***довольно неприятный***.  
Ну а по второму варианту, т.е. если говорящий не уверен, является ли этот газ отравляющим, то еще проще. Газ ***предположительно отравляющий***.

> Дело в том, что это не совсем авторская мысль, это перевод, тут уже другие требования.

Ого! А я тут распинаюсь... А ларчик просто открывался...

А с какого языка перевод? Откуда вообще в переводе слово "довольно"? Короче: "оригинал - в студию".
Если там английское ***enough***, то переводите ***достаточно***. Вроде бы и то же самое, но не совсем. Это известная ошибка не только  начинающих, но и маститых переводчиков. Не буду тут распространяться, но enough надо переводить как *довольно* только когда других вариантов не осталось.

Comment: "Тут скорее для качественных прилагательных (типа деревянный или врачебный)" - ??

Comment: Ээээ... перемудрил, конечно, при редактировании.  Спасибо.
При такой конструкции фразы надо "относительных". Прправил.

Comment: Господи, простите, пожалуйста, мне почему-то не пришло на почту уведомление о вашем ответе, и я его проглядела.
В оригинале It's quite noxious.
Но по сути мне было про данную конкретную фразу "довольно отравляющий" интересно, потому что переводчик настаивал, что это совершенно нормально звучит, а меня как-то она смущала. Вот и пришла свериться с коллективным разумом.

Comment: Не пришло, видимо потому, что я вставил ответ в текст основного сообщения. А по сути - понятно. Что  quite, что enough - это "сырой" перевод. Как термин не рассматривается, а в обычном понимании режет слух.